# Passing Activity as Parameter in Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have the notification defined as:

```
   private void sendNotification(String msg, Activity onClickActivity) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Send to the login activity, since if already a member and logged in, should be able to start that activity

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, onClickActivity), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
                .setContentTitle("Hello")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

as you can see, I wish to be able to allow dynamic references to the PendingIntent, so that a user may click on notification and subsequently access different activities given `Activity onClickActivity`. At present the error notes it cannot resolve constructor.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Intent` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) expects a `class`, not an `instance`. Just change your method signature to

```
private void sendNotification(String msg, Class<? extends Activity> onClickActivity) {
```